# Route select traffic from devices attached to certain ports on the network switch via OpenDNS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, modem

Ive got a home network as the diagram below, the modem / router (combined unit) is a [BT home hub 3](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/32813/c/1243/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDQ4MDQ0NTE3L3NpZC8tbmtXRS1CbQ%3D%3D) and the network switch is a [Netgear GS748Tv1](http://support.netgear.com/product/GS748Tv1).

There is a wifi mesh installed which uses Ubiquity UAP AC Pros (not yet installed) but my plan is to setup a 'guest wifi network' for kids to use and then have all the websites accessed through that network go through OpenDNS to filter out any adult content. There will be a main wifi network that will be unfiltered.

What im struggling to work out is at what point is i can route traffic from Any device connected to port 1, 2, 3, 4 20, 21, 30, 31 (these are the ports that the cat6 outlets in the kids rooms are connected to) on the Netgear switch via openDNS ? Would this be done at the router level or at the switch level (can DNS settings even be set at the switch level ?)

[image: network diagram]

Comment: Are all devices getting DHCP from the router? Not sure if it is possible with the gear that you have but you might be able put the kids on a different vlan.  You could have a separate DHCP server for the kids vlan and that would give them openDNS.  You would also have to check that the access points can have multiple vlans.

Answer (score 0):

There is no per application/port/gate DNS in any OS that I know. The closest is setting up a [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN), *i.e.*, a software-controlled separation of a LAN into non-intersecting subnets, to which different DHCP configurations apply.

In line of principle, you could even have separate gateways for different VLANs, but in your simple case it will be enough to establish different DNS servers for the default network, your children's network, and possibly your guest network. At my place, for instance, the guests' wifi network is referenced to outside DNS servers, so that they cannot resolve local host names. Since you are also planning on doing something similar, then the same solution applies to both problems.

Being one of the rebels of 1775-1783 I have no idea whether your BT router supports VLANs, you will have to check your documentation. If it does not, then my suggestion is that you place a DD-WRT/OpenWRT/Tomato router right behind the BT modem, and before the NetGear switch, because these fully support VLANs, see for instance [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Support). Just to relieve some of your stress, while under most cases DD-WRT/OpenWRT/Tomato need to be flashed to a router, [Buffalo](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless) sells **some** models with DD-WRT pre-installed.

Normally, I should have added that you also need a switch that supports VLANs, but, judging from [this Web page](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS748Tv1/GS748T_ds_03Feb05.pdf) (this is your switch, right?), you already have the requisite hardware.